# Command line upgrade after current version no longer supported

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

I was trying to install some php5 modules on my Virtual Private Server and they weren't found. The server runs Ubuntu 13.04. So I ran sudo apt-get update and noticed that many of the sites were not found. It looks like my version is not supported.

So I looked into how to upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu from the command line since I can only administer the server through ssh. All the stuff I found said that I needed either do-release-upgrade or update-manager, neither of which was on my system. So I searched for both with aptitude and only update-manager was found, so I thought I would give it a try.

Of course, I couldn't install it because the packages were not found, because my release is no longer supported.

Does this mean there is no way to upgrade the server remotely? Will I have to open a new VPS account just to get a fresh installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: Use the old released mirror as shown in http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release and install `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` to get the `do-release-upgrade` tool.